# 2006 model Polo hatchback 1.4 BLM engine overheating

Tags: vw

My water is always on max mark and when I drive the heat gauge remains normal. It starts smoking from the water bottle and the water starts boiling then I have to cool it down and fill water again till I can carry on.

There is no leak, the water and oil are not mixing.

The heat gauge is always normal, it never went up.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you've introduced an airlock into the system.  When you refill the coolant reservoir, are you doing it after the car has fully cooled?  You need to make sure that the heater control in the cabin is set all the way to HOT in order not to trap air in the heater core.  You are best filling the reservoir but leaving the cap off.  Running the engine at idle and squeezing the radiator bottom hose to expel any air from the system then topping it up to the max mark.  Do not allow the coolant level to ever go over the max mark.